# How to write a YAML script to change the screen resolution

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have created Azure Pipeline, where I needed to add a task to perform change in resolution while running my script. I know when we do it manually we only write below command as PowerShell DOS command. But I am not aware how to write that in YAML to add it as Inline script in pipeline

```
Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1366 -Height 768 -Force
```

Please let me know if you some other details or if you have any concern.

Purpose: The purpose of using this is because I have create a Selenium Automation. I have created Build solution to execute that however, I am facing an issue that due to pipeline execution running on low resolution, my automation was failing so thought of using powershell to change resolution

Comment: You need the explain this further. Afaik, [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) is not a **programming** language. It is an language for object notations often used in config files. Meaning, you can't directly execute it.

Comment: Pipelines are headless processes. They don't **have** a display resolution. What is your end goal here?

Comment: You can run a build agent as an interactive agent.  It can run UI automation that way and resolution might be important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute several commands in PS inline script mode:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          # Write your PowerShell commands here.
          Write-Host "Hello World"
          Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1366 -Height 768 -Force
          Write-Host "You can add more commands here"
```

The `Set-DisplayResolution` cmdlet is used to change the display resolution for a **Server Core** server. So you can't use this command for Windows 10... It means this command can't work until you're using a self-hosted agent (Server Core) to run the job.

About how to write a PS script to set the resolution when `Set-DisplayResolution` is not recognized you can check issue [How to set display resolution via PowerShell on Win10 Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/1493334/how-to-set-display-resolution-via-powershell-on-win10-pro).

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer:

See [This bit of microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) on how to create a step that executes a powershell script.

Here's a minimal example

```yaml
steps:
# whatever steps you have
- powershell: Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1366 -Height 768 -Force
# whatever other steps you have
```

#### Some Caveats

1. You may need to run your agent [interactively instead of as a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#interactive-or-service) especially if you plan on running GUI tests after you've resized the screen. Microsoft hosted agents *should* run in interactive mode, allowing you to resize the screen as you see fit.
2. Explore [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-autotest.screen-resolution-utility-task) and see if its worth using, especially if the powershell command keeps failing.

Comment: This is a good answer.  I personally had a lot more success with the extension mentioned.  If you choose to use the extension, just be aware that it will fail if you happen to be RDP onto the server when it executes.